Ubuntu 24.04.1 psql gives error error while loading shared libraries: libldap-2.5.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
I had psql 16 running on 22.04.4 and have upgraded to 24.04.1.
Postgres doesn't run now. There are no errors in the log. I do have warnings for every database:
WARNING:  database "test" has a collation version mismatch  
[104672] DETAIL:  The database was created using collation version 2.35, but the operating system provides version 2.39.  
[104672] HINT:  Rebuild all objects in this database that use the default collation  
and run ALTER DATABASE ds_test REFRESH COLLATION VERSION,   
or build PostgreSQL with the right library version.

At the end of the log I also see:
/usr/lib/postgresql/16/bin/postgres:   
error while loading shared libraries:   
libldap-2.5.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory  
no data was returned by command ""/usr/lib/postgresql/16/bin/postgres" -V"
program "postgres" is needed by pg_ctl   
but was not found in the same directory as "/usr/lib/postgresql/16/bin/pg_ctl"

Has anyone else seen anything similar? Maybe I should go back and reinstall 22.04.4 and wait for better results on the latest version. Let me know what I should try or any pointers.

I ended up redoing the installation which took 5 minutes and worked. I shouldn't have had to do that (I don't believe).
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
sudo apt update
sudo apt install postgresql-16 postgresql-contrib-16

sudo systemctl start postgresql
sudo systemctl enable postgresql

